# what kind of stanza is this?

Tags: poetry

> Had he and I but met
>
> By some old ancient inn,
>
> We should have set us down to wet
>
> Right many a nipperkin!

Source: The man he killed by Thomas Hardy

Comment: “The Man He Killed” uses a simple ABAB rhyme scheme and short iambic lines, mostly trimeter, with three “feet” (or six syllables) per line; only the third line in each stanza is longer, at four poetic feet. This simple, regular meter gives the poem a deceptively lighthearted tone, like a nursery rhyme. Its whimsical sound deepens the irony of the poem’s serious theme, raising questions about the ethics of war.

Comment: Many hymns have the 6-6-8-6 meter.